# Sherlock ActionBar Overflow Menu TextColor

Tags: android, android-actionbar, textcolor

I am trying to change the textcolor of the overflow menu on my action bar but nothing seems to work

```
  <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenuStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyActionWidgetTheme</item>
     <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/title</item>

</style>
<style name="MyPopupMenuStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/title</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/title</item>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `android:actionBarWidgetTheme`

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyStyle" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

The above will make the text red.

Comment: This seems to be using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Yes it will change the colour of the text used in the overflow menu but it also updates the colour of the text used on the action bar on tablets. Oops sorry, I'd still got actionMenuColor set to the wrong value too. Thanks this works great

Answer (score -2):

Use android:actionBarWidgetTheme

Comment: Could you explain how this attribute will specifically change only that Attribute asked about? And how to implement this solution for a specific colour?